# Razor Html Helper Function Data Bind

Tags: razor, knockout.js, asp.net-core-mvc

In asp.net 5 I have created an html helper function that takes in one parameter. On this view I am using Knockout js data binding and I need to figure out in the razor syntax on how to pass the variable in. Here is the code I have:

```
...

<tbody data-bind="foreach: filteredEvents">
    <tr class="@Html.GetEventLevelCss(event().EventLevel)">
        <td data-bind="text: event().LogDate"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: event().ClientName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: event().EventLevel"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: event().Version"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: event().LogDate"></td>
        <td>
            <a data-bind="attr: { href: '/Log/Detail/' + event().LogId }, text: 'View'"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
...
```

I am not sure how to data bind that event().EventLevel. When I run the code I am getting a 500 error.

Comment: can you try this `<tr data-bind="css:$root.someFunction.bind(event().EventLevel)"` > . in viewmodel query based on parameter passed and return class name

Comment: you can check here how it is done http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/25636/ . i am dynamically applying class based on data .

Comment: You cannot do this. Razor is executed on the server side while your Knockout code is running inside the browser. So you cannot pass in a Knockout/JavaScript object/value to a Razor helper... So you should re-write/move your `GetEventLevelCss`logic to JavaScrip....